# Multiple primary_key for has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

There is a model `Company` that has many `Disclosure` and `Statement`.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :disclosures
  has_many :statements
end
```

`Disclosure` and `Statement` both have `date` column.

And the `Statement` have a method like this:

```
def disclosures
  Disclosure.where(date: date, company_id: company_id)
end
```

It work's fine. But I think this kind of relation should write by `has_many` notation. But I couldn't find way to use multiple `primary_key` with `has_many`.

Is there a way to use multiple primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default Activerecord does not support composite keys, but using the following repo you should be able to:

> github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys

after that you should be able to use multiple primary keys:
a small example below

```
require 'composite_primary_keys'

class StringProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_keys = :entity_id, :property_id
    set_table_name "problem.string_property"
    attr_accessible :entity_id, :property_id, :value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late I know, but maybe this is interesting for others. To stick with your example you can try to build a custom scope, something along the lines of:

```
has_many :disclosures,
         -> (statement) { where("date = ? AND company_id = ?",
                                statement.date, statement.company_id) }
```

In case you don't want to look for statement_id in the Disclosure, use `unscope(where: :statement_id).where(...)` in the block.